# Hadoop mapreduce Word count of Multiple files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am newbee in Hadoop MapReduce. and I am doing word count. and input is number of text files and i have to represent frequency of each word from each different files and have to form table of term vector. I have read term vector is part of apache lucene library. and i am totally new to all these stuff, so i am not getting how to do it,

How can i do it..?
Thanks

```
Output should look like as follows in table format
       an apple is not orange the 
Doc1    1   5   8   22   0    32 
Doc2    0   6   10  19   0    13 
Doc3    3   12  15   4   8     5
```

This is my mapper class

```
public class Mapper2 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{   
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)  
    throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
// Get the file name
    FileSplit split = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
     String filename = split.getPath().getName().toString();

//   context.write(new Text(filename), new IntWritable(1));
    String[] Stopwords=   {"a","about","above","after","again","against","all","am","an",
            "and","any","are","as","at","be","by","com","for","from","how","in","it","of",
            "on","or","that","the","this","to","was","what","when","where","who","will","with",
            "is","do","not","of","I","This"};
    List<String> stopwordlist=Arrays.asList(Stopwords);
    String s = value.toString();
    for (String word : s.split("\\W+")) 
        {           
        if ((word.length() > 0)&&(!stopwordlist.contains(word))) 
            {   
            context.write(new Text(filename+word), new IntWritable(1));
            }       
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: i have done simple word count and removed stop words now i have to Represent input documents as a table of term vectors.... just now i read term vector is part of apache lucene. and i have no idea how to use it

Comment: Tell us how your final output should look ?, Also why are looking up on lucene for this word count problem ?

Comment: i have added output format in question above code. I just gone through lucene. because somewhere i read term vector(which is part of lecene) is used for indexing documents. Please Help me..